# Planar subgraph.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have to find the greatest planar subgraph of $K_{m,n}$ where $m,n\le3$.

So, I know it and i can drow the plane graph with an edge at most $6+2(m-3)$.

But I can't show that the graph is the greatest.

Can someone for help.

Comment: in what sense "greatest"? by vertex count? by edge count? by sum of these?

Comment: @gt6989b: I think the "maximal planar subgraph" is intended. It's not obviously clear to me that the answer is unique, even up to isomorphism.

Comment: @AndreaMori in what sense maximal? For example, $K_{3,3}$ is not planar, but $K_{2,3}$ is -- would that count, since it clearly has the largest number of vertices? Or we can add some edges t that

Comment: @gt6989b, maximal in the sense of being a subgraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of $K_{2,3}$ as a pair of blue vertices at $(\pm 1, 0)$ and the partition of 3 red vertices along the $y$-axis, at $(0,0), (0,\pm 1)$.

Now add another blue vertex at $(0,1/2)$ and connect to its neighbors on the $y$-axis, and the result is $K_{3,3}$ which is missing just one edge.

Adding the edge would make a full $K_{3,3}$ which is not planar, so in that sense, our graph is maximal...